# In Windows Forms, is there a control that shows a text overlay like a tooltip without all the tooltip behavior?

Tags: c#, winforms

I just want some kind of simple text overlay that shows for a few seconds when I tell it to, at a certain location, just like the normal tooltip.

However, I don't want the normal tooltip behavior of automatically showing when the mouse hovers over the control it's associated with. Can I disable this behavior on the normal tooltip, or is there some other control I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just call the tooltip yourself:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
  tip.ToolTipTitle = "Title";
  tip.Show("Hello", button1, 10, button1.Height - 6, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I'm doing. But I think if you hover the mouse over button1 you will find that the tooltip will still show. It's attached to it.

Comment: @IsaacB If you use SetToolTip, then it's attached, but by using Show, it doesn't-- at least not in my test environment.

Comment: Yes you are right, with your example it doesn't attach, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong. I'm just losing it I guess. Anyway, thanks for your help it solved the problem.